# Alfresco dynamic link in dashboard

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want a dynamic link to be generated and placed in a users' alfresco dashboard. The link would be say "inbox" which will have to be in the following format http://www.mysite.com/preauth.jsp?email=hello@domain.com . The only dynamic part of the link would be hello@domain.com which will be the email address of the user currently logged in. How can this be achieved Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Using alresco community 4.2a

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to implement this using a dashlet then take a look at will's sample dashlet on github: https://github.com/share-extras/sdk-sample-dashlet

All you need to do is to modify the ftl of the dashlet:

```
...normal html
<a href ="http://www.mysite.com/preauth.jsp?email=${user.email}">link</a>
```

Another approach is to add your link to Alfresco Share's header & add the following item (http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Share_Header):

```
<item type="external-link" id="pre-auth">http://www.mysite.com/preauth.jsp?email={useremail}</item>
```

{useremail} is an unkown token here, thus you'll have to customize site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\header\header.get.html.ftl & add your token there (sorry only 4.1 code as i don't have a 4.2 in-place):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
   var ${jsid} = new Alfresco.component.Header("${jsid}").setOptions(
   {
      siteId: "${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}",
      siteTitle: "${siteTitle?js_string}",
      minSearchTermLength: ${args.minSearchTermLength!config.scoped["Search"]["search"].getChildValue("min-search-term-length")},
      tokens:
      {
         site: "${page.url.templateArgs.site!""}",
         pageid: "${page.url.templateArgs.pageid!""}",
         userid: "${user.name?js_string}",
         useremail: "${user.email?js_string}",
      }
   }).setMessages(${messages});
   Alfresco.util.createTwister.collapsed = "${collapsedTwisters?js_string}";
//]]></script>
```

Comment: After I posted the question, I dug around that the 2nd approach you have provided is the way to go . Went ahead and modified share-config.xml and added the link. BUT  ${user.email} is not getting picked up. I tried a couple of other tags as well. None works. Any help?

Comment: edited my answer - you'll have to customize site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\header\header.get.html.ftl - pls use 4.2-compatible best-practice here - my 4.1 example is dirty

Comment: I understand the code that you have given is not 4.2 compliant, but when I copy paste it on top of the header.get.html.ftl , alfresco throws a whole bunch of errors and not display the header. Any help?